# How to get the service name of a local SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, service

I need to get the service name of a locally installed SQL Server instance.

I wish it could be as simple as querying the instance with `SELECT @@SERVICENAME` as I have seen at multiple places, however, for me that query returns `SQLEXPRESS`, while the service name as seen from SCM is `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`.

Is there another way to do this? It doesn't have involve querying the instance. As I said, the instance is running locally.

The reason I need to do this is because I am installing a service which depends on the instance of SQL Server running, and I need to specify the name of the sql server service as a dependency in the service installer. If there is a better way to do this feel free to suggest it.

Comment: The name of the service can change, it depends on the name of the instance. Clearly you are running a SQL Server Express instance, however, someone else might have a non-Express instance with the default name, or they might have a named instance.

Comment: I know. That's why I'm asking "how to get the name of the service of an SQL Server instance".

Comment: What does commandprompt > `sqlcmd -L` return?

Comment: It returns the names of the sql instances, but I want the service name.

Comment: The [windows service reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-reference) seems like the place to start. It has a function to enumerate all installed services. A simple search on "enumerate sql server instances" will find many suggestions - much depends on your context. Perhaps your installation tool offers something? And consider what to do if there are multiple instances - which one is the dependency?